# UIButton title issue on iPhone6 with iOS9.3.2

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-6, ios9.3.2

I created button using storyboard and set the tittle with out any underline using custom font. But i got underline under title of button in only iPhone6 with iOS 9.3.2 but not all devices. Please see the below image. I have checked all apple documents but i didn't get any solution. Is the iOS problem or iPhone problem or any settings on iPhone6 related button?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `Setting app` in your iphone, Go to `general` then go to `accessibility`, under `accessibility` turn off the `switch` for **`Button shapes`**

It may solve your problem i think. Because if you have used button with type `system` then it will use system's configuration for button!!

Comment: Excellent. I didn't check it previously in settings. Thanks a lot.